# How to get all orders over period by a collection in Magento?

Tags: sql, magento, collections

I need to retrieve a collection of all orders taken over a period of time.

Also I need to query the number of orders per day taken.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$fromDate = '2016-01-15 00:00:00';
    $toDate = '2016-02-15 00:00:00';

    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));

    $orders->getSelect()
        ->columns('COUNT(created_at)')
        ->group('created_at');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should give you what you need.  Personally, I'd run from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.  Please note that this will be based on UTC (as that's how Magento stores times/dates).  You might need to offset these to the store timezone.

```
$fromDate = '2016-03-01 00:00:00';
$toDate = '2016-03-31 23:59:59';

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq'=>$fromDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq'=>$toDate));

$orders->getSelect()
    ->columns( 'COUNT(*) AS orders_count' )
    ->group( 'DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d-%m-%y")' );

foreach($orders as $order) {
    // logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude thats exactly what i was looking for.